# POST method in Spring Boot REST service (external Tomcat) return 404 error

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, spring-boot, http-post

I created a REST web service using Spring Boot. 
The project is configured to use an external Tomcat.
When using Tomcat 8 it connects successfully and get good responses when i call my GET methods.

However, the POST methods return 404 errors.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hashkey")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class StringHashingController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody HashedStringsList hashMe(@RequestParam(value="caller", required=true) String callerId, @RequestBody StringHashingRequestBodyParams hashParam) {
        HashedStringsList pList = new HashedStringsList();
        //...
        return pList;
    }
}
```

I have no problem calling the same post method locally in the IDE (Intellij) through running 'Spring Boot Configuration'.

Is there anything I need to configure in Tomcat or in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your get and post request with params?

Comment: when I copied my requests here, I saw the issue...

Comment: i called the get method:
`<host>:8080/<application-name>/my-get`
and for the POST request I omitted the application name...
`<host>:8080/my-post`

Thanks @Rahul for asking the right question!

Comment: You have to use `<host>:8080/<app-name>/hashkey` for the POST request. First try to test using rest clients `Postman` or `Advanced Rest Client`